# Mouse Lock API in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, mouseevent

I am trying to lock mouse in a website using [this tutorial](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/pointerlock/intro/). I understand, that it is still not standardized, but I would like to use it anyway. I think I have done everything as they described. My file is here: http://www.ivank.net/veci/mlock.html

Do you know where is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Oh, I solved it.

The element, which requests lock, must have focus when requesting! Here it is described https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/pointerlock/raw-file/tip/index.html#widl-Element-requestPointerLock-void

It gives you lots of struggling, when you read third-party tutorials instead of reading the official (unfinished, though) specification.